# Grid of labels - how to set constraints in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to build user interface for my app and I have to use 6x3 grid of labels. I put them in the View. Simply it looks like this:

```
Label  Label  Label

Label  Label  Label

Label  Label  Label

Label  Label  Label

Label  Label  Label

Label  Label  Label
```

When I'm trying to automatically add missing constraints it looks bad.

I tried to use a lot of settings but I haven't got appriopriate look yet. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6x3 grid of labels ? What about collectionView? and you haven't got a problem with 1000000 constraints? U can add custom collectionView with size/color/count of objects .......

Comment: Oh, on problem, i'd like to help))

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like you need to use the labels vs a collection view, you could:

1) Add constraints from one label to the next with equal height / width.
2) Add constraints from the first label to container leading / top.
3) Add from top right label to trailing / top.
4) Wind your way around specifying where they should be next to.

If they all equal width / height, I think you'll be able to get them all to stretch like you are looking for.